# EasyMock AssertionError when invoking Logger.error(String, Throwable)

Tags: log4j, easymock, printstacktrace

I am seeing assertion error when I include a Throwable while invoking Log4j.error method. I do have Logger.class, PrintWriter.class, AuthenticationException.class in the @PreparateForTest block. I do not see the error if I do not pass the Throwable as an argument.

What am I missing in setting up mocks correctly?

```
    Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: 
      Unexpected method call AuthenticationException.printStackTrace(java.io.PrintWriter@2c64e8ad):
            at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
            at com.xxx.yy.security.client.ClientTest.authenticateFail(ClientTest.java:282)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
            ... 23 more
```

JUnit test code snippet is as below:

```
    AuthenticationException mockAuthException = PowerMock
                        .createMock(AuthenticationException.class);
    PrintWriter mockPrintWriter = PowerMock
                        .createMock(PrintWriter.class);
    Logger mockLogger = PowerMock.createMock(Logger.class);
    String message = "blah";
    mockLogger.error(message, mockAuthException);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();

    mockAuthException.printStackTrace(mockPrintWriter);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();
```

Code snippet that is causing the issue is as below:

```
    try{
    .
    .
    }catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("SOME MESSAGE HERE", ex);
        throw ex;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting an  `Unexpected method call error` which can be solved as follows:

```
AuthenticationException mockAuthException = EasyMock.createNiceMock(AuthenticationException.class);
PrintWriter mockPrintWriter = EasyMock.createNiceMock(PrintWriter.class);
Logger mockLogger = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Logger.class);
String message = "blah";
mockLogger.error(message, mockAuthException);
EasyMock.expectLastCall();

mockAuthException.printStackTrace(mockPrintWriter);
EasyMock.expectLastCall();
```

The changes over here are using easymock instead of powermock,and creating a niceMock instead of normal mock.

The `createMock(..)` method is strict and can not identify if a method is internally called or not,but when you use `createNiceMock(..)` this check is ignored and you do not get a UnexpectedMethodCall error

Hope it helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`LOGGER.error("SOME MESSAGE HERE", ex);`

This line appears to be calling the `printStacktrace` method of the `ex`, i.e the `AuthenticationException` type. Since you've mocked it, you have to tell the behavior the object (the mock, technically) should behave in, when this call is encountered.

You have 3 choices, apart from relaxing the `verification` of course thru the use of `nice mocks`, assuming you really expect this exception to be thrown (your question is a bit vague about it):

- See if you can expect the `LOGGER.error("SOME MESSAGE HERE", ex);`, i.e mock the `LOGGER`. The `LOGGER` appears to be a `static` variable, but you seem to be using `Powermock`, so I don't think you'll have any problems mocking it, but if you do have concerns mocking the `LOGGER`, read on
- Tell `Easymock` how it's supposed to respond when it encounters the `printStacktrace` method call on the mock object `mockAuthException` by placing an expectation on it like this (`printStacktrace` being a `void` method) before you `replay` the mock:

  `mockAuthException.printStacktrace(); expectLastCall().andDoSomethingIfNeeded();`
- Don't mock the `AuthenticationException` type at all unless it's absolutely necessary - it does look like you can do without mocking it, say, by creating a `Stub` of the type.